# Less : Finding index of column and apply styles

Tags: less

I am new to `less`

What I am trying to achieve is, I want to give a class to `th` element and then want to apply the same styles for all the `td` having same index as the `th`. So basically I am trying to find out the index of `th` so that I can use `:nth-child()` for that index.

Is that possible with less?

**Edit**

So I am trying to achieve something like this

```
td:nth-child(@index_of_th_with_particular_class)
{ 

}
```

Comment: You mean writing selectors like `th:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(1) { color: red; }`? I am not quite getting the question. Can you maybe add an example of what output you need?

Comment: @Harry - I have updated my question of what I am exactly looking for

Comment: Nope this wouldn't be possible because the Less compiler wouldn't have any clue about your HTML structure at the time of compilation.

Comment: Oh ok! So I have to use jquery. I was trying to avoid jquery for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope you mean like this, please take a look at the [sample pen](http://codepen.io/YaserAliPeedikakkal/pen/kXpAak)

CSS & HTML

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
tr:nth-child(3) td {
  background: yellow;
}
tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(5) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <table>
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
                <td>Test data</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

LESS

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
tr {
  &:nth-child(3) {
    td {
      background: yellow;
    }
  }
  &:nth-child(4) {
    td {
      &:nth-child(5) {
        background: red;
      }
    }
  }
}
```